# How can I type check ReactNavigation's navigation using NavigationHelpersCommon?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, typechecking

I am new to the typescript screen, so the answer may be an obvious one. I am passing ReactNavigation's navigator as a prop to a functional component and I currently type check using `navigator: object`, but would love to use the typescript definition from ReactNavigation, so my code doesn't complain about things like "navigation.navigate" and so forth.

I found the type definition inside `@react-navigation/core/lib/typescript/src/types.d.ts`; however it is not exported.

I also found this in the ReactNavigation documentation, which indicates that I may be approaching this completely at the wrong angle.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#annotating-usenavigation

Or maybe I should find a way to use the `useNavigation` hook, but that would require me to use use component that wasn't a function like I prefer.

Bottomline: How can I import the `NavigationHelpersCommon` declaration to type check against?

Answer (score 4):

Just as you can see from the doc you linked, typing a functional component is a multiple steps process.

You have to type all your screens, based on their names and eventually their params, and with this types, use it to create the types for each screens.

--

For example, if you have a `Home` component without any param and another screen called `About` with a required param of `name`, something like that:

```
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={Home}
  />
  <Stack.Screen
    name="About"
    component={About}
    initialParams={{ name: 'Gabriel' }}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

First create a type corresponding to your screens in its own file and export it to use it at different places:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  About: { name: string };
};
```

So now, when you define the Stack Navigator, you can use your created type:

```
import { RootStackParamList } from 'your/file';

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
```

The last thing is to create the necessary types for each pages (or maybe create an util or something with `Typescript` to only have a single declaration which takes the page name as a param). You can do so in the file with the first type, which now look like this:

```
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';


export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  About: { name: string };
};

export type HomeScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  'Home'
>;

export type AboutScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  'About'
>;
```

Finally in your functional components, depending on which page you are on, you can have a fully typed `navigation` prop:

```
import { HomeScreenNavigationProp } from 'your/file';

type Props = {
  navigation: HomeScreenNavigationProp;
};
```